# use virtual fields for Postgres in cakephp1.3

Tags: postgresql, cakephp-1.3

I want to use Virtual Fields to concatinate wo fields together that will used in my dropdown .like firstname and last name.

It shows fine if i dont use any separator.

But I got an error while i concatinate those fields with space,star or smothing else.

Here is my code:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
             'name' => 'CONCAT(MaterialOwner.first_name,"-",MaterialOwner.last_name)'
        );
```

NOTE: I am working in PostgreSQL. May be this is an issue in postgres.

Plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should post the error you get.

The problem is that PostgreSQL uses only ' for strings. The " is used for tables/columns/functions names. So use the code like:

```
CONCAT(MaterialOwner.first_name,'-',MaterialOwner.last_name)
```

Comment: Thanx for Your reply Szymon.. But now it gives another Error. Like: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ')' in /var/www/inventoryphase2/app/models/material_owner.php on line 8